# How to get wiremock to return 404 on error instead of 500 when the response bodyFileName is not found

Tags: wiremock

I'm looking at getting Wiremock to return a 404 instead of a 500 when it fails to find a response file. I have the following stub:

```json
{
    "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "urlPathPattern": "/store/item/.*"
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "bodyFileName": "item{{request.pathSegments.[2]}}.json",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "transformers": ["response-template"]
    }
}
```

An example would be to return a 404 if there was a request for /store/item/1234 and item1234.json did not exist.

Comment: could you define stubs in code using Wiremock fluent API instead of using JSON definition?

Comment: Unfortunately not, eventually this will be maintained by a QA team that may or may not have programming experience. I assume you were going to suggest something along the line of .willReturn() would have a conditional passed on checking if a file exists.

Comment: Java API is more flexible and you could implement any logic there. You could try to implement custom transformer and then use it in JSON definition https://wiremock.org/docs/extending-wiremock/